Two Way Anova with Heteroscedasticity
I'm trying to run a two way anova test but the homoscedasticity condition is not met. My analysis is not balanced and I have over 3000 observations in my sample. Is it okay to proceed even if the categories do not have equal variance? Below are a boxplot of the different possible combinations and a table with the average in each category.This is the code I ran. Is there a way to run a test that accounts for heteroscedasticity?
reg <- aov(depression ~ classification + diversityLessThan, 
           data=dataset)
summary(reg)



There are many similar posts, have a look at this stored search Many possibilities, bootstrap, robust standard errors, or you can look at gamlss as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239335/analyzing-reaction-time-data-by-implementing-gamm-analyses-with-non-normal-distr
